# React Component this.variable not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this react component and I have created a const see below:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const mytext = 'Some Text';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         {this.mytext}
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

This const is not rendering mytext when I use {this.mytext}

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: `const this.mytext = 'Some Text';` and `{mytext}`......!

Comment: data type of mytext is const . So you need change it {this.mytext} to {mytext}

Comment: @Jai I think const this.mytext = 'Some Text'; is wrong syntax.

Comment: @Ved that's exactly what these suspention points + exclamation point meant

Comment: @Sebas I did not get you. Please explain.

Comment: @Ved no big deal I guess :-) but I think Jai was criticizing that syntax as well :)

Comment: @Sebas Ah!!. Got it. I tested const this.mytext = 'Some Text', after your comment and wonderning .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{this.mytext}` should be   `{mytext}`

And if you want to declare a global variable of type **const** than you need to define it like this

```
    const mytext = 'Some Text';
    export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();

      }

  render() {
        return (
          <div>
             {mytext}
          </div>

        );
      }
```

EDIT 1. The better approcah to declare a global varibale can be:

```
export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.mytext = "VED"//you can use it now anywhere inside your file
      }
```

Comment: So I can't define the variable inside the component?

Comment: No. You can define like this.mytext, but can't const  mytext.